# How to sort the content of a text file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, text

I have the following text inside a file:

```
git dosbox keepassxc bmon wavemon htop btop ncdu testdisk filelight \
        virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-guest-additions-iso \
        libreoffice-base duf byobu libreoffice-base libreoffice-templates \
        libreoffice-math libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-l10n-es \
        libreoffice-help-es libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-numbertext \
        libreoffice-librelogo default-jdk default-jre ant subversion \
        mercurial p7zip-full kate codeblocks qtcreator  build-essential \
        qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qt5-qmake cmake guvcview gnome-boxes \
        obs-studio  qemu-system libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system \
        bridge-utils virtinst libvirt-daemon samba openssh-server remmina \
        codium code gcc make gcc-avr gdb-avr avr-libc avrdude minicom \
        binutils-avr esptool audacious audacious-plugins audacious qmmp putty \
        putty-tools nextcloud-desktop screen smartmontools virt-manager \
        listserialportsc jstest-gtk slic3r meshlab openscad openscad-mcad \
        screenkey shotwell barrier peek clamav clamtk clamav-daemon \
        mixxx git-cola kdiff3 meld thunderbird thunderbird-locale-es nala \
        vkeybd vmpk certbot sqlitebrowser handbrake nmap leocad ldraw-parts \
        wings3d krfb krdc exfatprogs kdiskmark filezilla trash-cli kmag \
        kronometer keepass2 mono-complete stacer shc konversation meson \
        ninja-build ppa-purge zeal devhelp
```

I want to order all words and produce an orderdered file.

I tried with sort, but don't know if maybe i need another tool

Comment: `sort` sorts lines. You'll need to put each argument word on a separate line, sort that, then combine them back into a single line to make them arguments to `git`

Comment: Note that general questions about using UNIX tools belong on [unix.se], not here; Stack Overflow is specific to questions about _writing code_.

Comment: You can use `tr ' ' '\n'` to turn the spaces into newlines. You'll need to remove the backslashes first.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: remove git from the text file and then use below code to sort all the arguments - - >

`commands=$(for x in $(cat file.txt); do echo $x; done | sort | grep -v '\\' | tr '\n' ' ');
echo "git $commands"`

If you are satisfied with the output then add ` | sh` at the end on the line to execute it

`commands=$(for x in $(cat file.txt); do echo $x; done | sort | grep -v '\\' | tr '\n' ' ');
echo "git $commands" | sh`

Answer (score 1):

The most complicated part is indenting and adding breaks at appropriate points.

A Perl idea:

```
perl -0777aE '
    for ( sort grep !/\\/, @F ) {
        if (77 < $l + length) {
            $s .= "\\\n        ";
            $l = 8;
        }
        $s .= "$_ ";
        $l += 1 + length;
    }
    chop $s;
    say $s;
' textfile
```

- `-0777` - use null as record separator (ie. if no nulls, read entire file as single record)
- `-a` - autosplit record on whitespace and store in array `@F`
- `-E` - like `-e` but allows use of `say`
- `grep !/\\/, @F` - filter out array elements that contain backslash
- `sort @arr` - sort an array
- `$s` - a string to collect data until we are ready to print (starts empty)
- `$l` - the length of the current line of output (starts as zero)
- `for (@arr) { cmd; ... }` - run commands for each element of array, setting `$_` to the element being processed
- `length` - function returning number of characters in `$_`
- `if (77 < $l + length)` - test if line would become too long ( 77 allows a line with trailing space and backslash to fit in no more than 79 characters)

  - if so, append backslash, newline and indentation for the next line; and reset line length
- `$s .= "$_ "` - append the element and a trailing space
- `$l += 1 + length` - add length of element (and trailing space) to line length
- `chop $s` - delete the extraneous space added after the final element
- `say $s` - output the final result, appending a newline

---

Using just common unix utilities, you can approximate (but first line may be underfilled):

```
<textfile tr -s '[[:space:]\\]' '\n' |
sort |
fmt -69 |
sed '
    1! s/^/        /
    $! s/$/ \\/
'
```

Comment: both of these may also underfill the second-last line (don't need to allow for trailing space+backslash, so one extra element may fit without wrapping)

Comment: It seems the coreutils version of `fmt` uses a much more sophisticated algorithm (that tries to balance the length of all lines)  than the simple greedy approach I use in the perl script.